# FogBugz On Demand + online source control at low/no cost?

Tags: visual-studio, version-control, fogbugz, fogbugz-on-demand

I have a project in the free hosted [FogBugz On Demand](http://www.fogcreek.com/FogBugz/IntrotoOnDemand.html) (FOD) product right now. This is great for feature/issue tracking. But I've been working from a codebase that is solely on my development machine. I'd like to collaborate with another guy who is thousands of miles from me. So we need a source control solution (SCM)!

I use Visual Studio (2005, but can upgrade to later versions as needed).

I am aware that FogBugz [can integrate](http://www.fogcreek.com/FogBugz/docs/70/topics/advanced/SourceControlIntegration.html) with a number of source control systems.

So now the question is: which **online** SCM products can integrate well with FOD and VS? And which ones do so well at low or no cost, for a small code repository. And where might I find a proven recipe for putting this together.

I'm open to other solutions which provide the same functionality. Please don't suggest Trac - I regard it highly, but I want the features of FOB (especially the evidence based scheduling) in my issue tracking solution. So really, I need to combine FOB + VS + some online SCM product into a low or no cost solution for two coders to collaborate on.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Well, the obvious solution is to go with the product designed with FogBugz on Demand in mind:

[Kiln, from Fog Creek](http://www.fogcreek.com/Kiln/)

It is in beta right now, and I don't know what the waiting times to get into beta are like with it, but it might be worth a look for you.

Comment: This would be the real hotness. As I wrote the question I found myself thinking "I can't imagine this idea has NOT occurred to Joel & team many times!"

I have signed up. If I get in, this is the answer! if not, I am still looking. Thank you!

Comment: I switched my answer to Kiln. Today they invited me in. It's definitely better than Bitbucket, although Bitbucket is pretty darn good (the proprietor helped me personally with an issue, and I wasn't even a paying customer).

Answer (score 2):

I'm currently working with another developer and I have an SVN server set up at home.  I've got it hooked up to WebSVN so that we can access it through port 80 and all works like a charm.  We've got it hooked into FogBugz on Demand.

You should be able to use a service like DynDNS (or similar) to keep them linked if you don't have a static IP address.  I've got a static IP which alleviates this need, but it's free and allows access to my SVN repo from the office or to the other developer I'm working with.

I can't speak for online services though... I haven't used any of them.  I know this isn't strictly the answer you're looking for, but thought I'd throw it out there because of the fact that it would be free.

Comment: Yeah, I considered doing something like this, but on an hosted VM or VPS. I hope not to have to go to those lengths, though. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Ah - but if I do have to do it this way - do you have any links to full recipe for implementing it?

Comment: I can probably help you through it if you need it - look up my email address on my profile and we can discuss.

Comment: It took me hours of trawling through sparse badly written answers on various forums to get SVN/WebSVN working together nicely - I never came across a full recipe for it getting it set up on Windows.

Comment: Thanks for the extended replies. Yup, exactly what I hope NOT to have to replicate. If I end up going this way and we do any emails, I'll definitely try to make a nice recipe out of the results and make it public, linked from here. But At the moment I have my hopes focused on that Kiln beta!

Comment: @quux: I had my hopes out for the Kiln beta too - but it was taking too long so I gave up and pounded my head with rocks to get SVN/WebSVN/FogBugz all hooked up together.  Maybe I'll set up a blog post this weekend covering the recipe I used to get it all up and running - if my other duties don't get in the way.

Comment: @quux: I notice your added comment about Trac - I *was* using that, but that was an unimaginable pain in the ass to get set up and hooked up to SVN.  It probably took me a day or two in all to actually get it working nicely.  Then I saw FOD at DevDays and switched over immediately.  Goodbye Trac and good riddance.

Comment: @benAlabaster - I'm surprised to hear of your difficulties with Trac and SVN integration. I've done it several times, from scratch. Have used and written some of the recipes @ the Trac project itself - though these were new setups (maybe you were trying to integrate existing SVN setups?). It's not Trac setup I need to avoid; it's the lack of FOD features, really. We're heading way offtopic here, but I did want to respond because the response may illuminate other answerers!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't get into Kiln beta (or don't want the extra cost once it's out of beta), you should try mercurial.

I'm not sure how good the VS integration is, but I've heard it's getting better.

You can host a mercurial server at bitbucket.org for not much money, which now has (untested by me) Fogbugz integration (http://www.bitbucket.org/help/service-integration/)

Comment: And they have a free plan for <150MB of data. Perfect.
Kiln looks nice, but it won't be the answer until it's out of beta and people can sign up for immediate accounts. Too bad!

Answer (score 0):

http://beanstalkapp.com/

They seem to offer Subversion hosting for a small project like yours for $15/month.  Not sure if that qualifies for 'low' cost, but if the source code you are developing means anything to you (which I assume it would!) $15 a month seems pretty cheap for a reliable source repository.

I don't work for or represent that company, just something I found when looking for subversion hosting.

Comment: I use DreamHost for my SVN hosting (and web hosting and ROR test server). It comes out at less than 10 a month. I'm not sure how well it plays with FOD though.

Comment: Right, I briefly looked at BeanStalk and Unfuddle, based on answers to similar questions here on SO. They are within the range of affordability. I have not yet located any clear concise recipes for the FOD+Beanstalk or FOD+Unfuddle or FOD+$OtherOnlineSCM integration, though.